# c++ template specialization, a template keyword in angle brackets

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, template-meta-programming

I got this code from boost::hana:

```
template <typename Storage>
struct KeyAtIndex {
    template <std::size_t i>
    using apply = decltype(hana::first(hana::at_c<i>(std::declval<Storage>())));
};

template <typename ...Pairs>
struct make_map_type {
    using Storage = hana::basic_tuple<Pairs...>;
    using HashTable = typename detail::make_hash_table<
        detail::KeyAtIndex<Storage>::template apply, sizeof...(Pairs)
    >::type;
    using type = detail::map_impl<HashTable, Storage>;
};
```

I wonder what's the mean of `detail::KeyAtIndex<Storage>::template`, why the `template` keyword is used here? Is there something in c++ iso standard can explain the use?

Comment: Look at [where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: @Jarod42 Thans a lot.